# Highcharts: create a simple line graph with json data

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts, I would like to create a simple line graph with datetime on the x-axis and number on the y-axis. The data will come from a RESTful endpoint as json

in this format

```
{"lineChartData":[{"date":"1373169600000","roi":"-2.001282"},{"date":"1373083200000","roi":"-3.001282"}]}
```

I have already converted the date in milliseconds. I'm looking for a solution or similar example to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that works for me is to loop through the json data to create Highcharts compatible format:

```
 function requestData(event) {
            var chartData=[];
            $.getJSON("rest/portfolio/rois", function(data) {
                $.each(data.lineChartData, function(key, val) {
                    chartData.push([parseFloat(val.date),parseFloat(val.roi)]);

                  });
                chart.series[0].setData(chartData);
            });

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution for your case is by looping through your json data and create points and add them to an array. Each point has to be set using its X and Y attributes, for example:

point = { x: 137.... , y: -2.0..... } poin2 ... and so forth..

array = [point, point2, ... ]

series: array

you can find more info in http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

hope helps

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution by myself which is pretty close to what you have recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this which I previously answered in different question

you can try this code to make x-axis in 12hour time format

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Hours of the Day'
    },
    type: 'datetime',

    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
        hour: '%I %p',
        minute: '%I:%M %p'
    }
},
```

Also for "tooltip" try this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return ''+
                "" +
                'Time: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M %p', this.x);
    }
},
```

And of course series would be:

```
series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 22, 1, 15), 12.7], 
            [Date.UTC(2012, 3, 24, 3, 20), 13.5],  //put your data array here
            [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 22, 2, 25), 18.8]
        ]
    }]
```

Hope it could solve your problem. Thanks.